# Any way to resolve this Microsoft Teams bug?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have MS Teams running on my laptop and I frequently switch monitors from one room to another. With MS Teams, most of the times, if there is any message pop-up on the bottom right, it leaves a blank tile which doesn't go away when I open the message or teams. It goes away only when I restart Teams. Is there any way to avoid this bug or any solution?

Screenshot below to show what happens. This tile gets stuck overlaying everything else.

[image]

Comment: Maybe Windows-native notifications could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the three dots on the top right, then Settings, then Notifications, click Custom and turn off the "banners" by clicking the Edit buttons below.

[image: The three dots are next to your profile picture on the top left]

[image]

Comment: it is already off

Comment: @dsauce Edited.